# Как достать объект через Hibernate по его полю, а не по id?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

Собственно мне нужно вытащить автора книг по его имени а не по `id`

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Author getAuthorById(int id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Author author = session.get(Author.class, id);
        logger.info("Class load: " + author);
        return author;
    }
```

Как это сделать?

Слышал про `createCriteria`, но он *deprecated*.

Comment: Версия Hibernate >= 5.2?

Comment: [CriteriaQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть два способа - c помощью запроса на [JPQL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language) и с помощью Criteria API. Объявлена устаревшей специфическая для Hibernate версия Criteria API, а новая версия, соответствующая JPA, вполне применима.

Вариант на JPQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Author where name = :name");
query.setParameter("name", "Howard Phillips Lovecraft");
Author author = query.getSingleResult();
```

Вариант на Criteria API:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Author> criteria = builder.createQuery(Author.class);
Root<Author> root = criteria.from(Author.class);
ParameterExpression<String> nameParam = builder.parameter(String.class);
criteria.select(root)
        .where(builder.equal(root.get("name"), nameParam));

Query<Author> query = session.createQuery(criteria);
query.setParameter(nameParam, "Howard Phillips Lovecraft");
Author author = query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ! Работают оба варианта.

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо использовать `createQuery()`, что в свою очередь предпологает использование HQL.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String queryString = "from Author where " + name + "= :value";
Query queryObject = session.createQuery(queryString);
queryObject.setParameter("value", value);
List<Author> list = queryObject.list();
```

где `name` это название поля, содержажего имя, а имя содержится в переменной `value`.